# Eclipse complains about following String.format usage

Tags: java, string, format, string.format

The program consists of the two following classes and should print time.
Within the class `Melons` Eclipse gives me an error under the method `String.format` and I do not understand why

```
public class Melons {

    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public void setTime(int h, int m, int s)
    {
        hour = ((h>=0 || h<24) ? h : 0);
        minute = ((m>=0 || m<60) ? m : 0);
        second = ((s>=0 || s<24) ? s : 0);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        // Problem here
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", 
                             ((hour==0||hour==12) ? 12 : hour%12), 
                             minute,
                             second,
                             (hour<12 ? "AM" : "PM"));          
    } 
 }

class Apples
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        Melons melonsObject = new Melons();
        System.out.println(melonsObject.toString());
        melonsObject.setTime(13, 35, 9);
        System.out.println(melonsObject.toString());
    }   
}
```

Comment: And if you hover over the underlined line, what does it say? (Why do we have to tell you this...?)

Comment: This seems to compile for me. Are you sure that's the offending code?

Comment: what you mean with offending code?

Comment: i have a red error line under the word "format"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) has been a member method of `String` since Java 1.5. Ensure you are using this version or greater and that you don't have another `String` class on your classpath.

Comment: you need to tell us what the problem is:- old version of Java or another `String` class in the classpath?

Comment: what you mean in another string class in the classpath?

Comment: my eclipse version is quite new

Comment: tnx! I changed in the java compiler section (project->properties) the version of the compiler compliance level, from 1.4 to 1.7 and this is working :)